# Simple copying pointers with Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to modify the contents of one pointer using another. I want string2 to point to what string1 points to, so that when I modify string2, it modifies string1. How can I do this?

```
 NSString *string1=@"hello";
 NSString *string2=string1;
 string2=@"changed";
 NSLog(@"string1:%@, string2:%@", string1, string2); //"string1:hello, string2:changed"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make a second assignment to your `string2` variable you are not modifying the contents of what the variable currently refers to, in this case the same `NSString` as variable `string1` refers to, but rather your are modifying to what `string2` refers.

A picture (code) is worth a thousand words:

Every object and variable has an internal name, usually called its *address*. Addresses are usually written as hexadecimal numbers, e.g. `0xdeadbeef`, the *value* of the number is not important to you - it is just a label.

When you write:

```
NSString *string1 = @"Hello!";
```

the right-hand side asks Objective-C to create an `NSString` with the value `@"Hello"`, the result of this is an address, say `0xfeeddeaf`. The lhs-side asks for a variable capable of holding an `NSString *` in it - a reference to an `NSString`; to call this variable `string1`; and to store the result of the rhs, `0xfeeddeaf`, into it.

When you now write:

```
NSString *string2 = string1;
```

this results in a variable `string2` also containing `0xfeeddeaf`. *There is no linkage between the contents of `string1` and `string2`, assignment just copies a value (which is an address in the case).*

Finally when you write:

```
string2 = @"changed";
```

this creates an `NSString` with the value of `@"changed"` with an address, say, of `0xbeedcafe` and stores that in `string2`. So now `string1` contains `0xfeeddeaf` which is the address of `@Hello`, and `string2` contains `0xbeedcafe` which is the address of `@"changed"`.

I'm guessing when you write that you're "trying to modify the contents of one pointer using another" what you want is for `string1` and `string2` to refer to the *same* object, whose value you can modify. You can't modify the value of an `NSString`, they are non-modifiable (immutable) once created. Instead you have to use an `NSMutableString` *and* you need to use a method to change the value of an `NSMutableString` object - as the above shows if you use assignment you change which object is referred to, not the contents of the object.

Assuming you are using ARC[*] then changing your code to:

```
NSMutableString *string1 = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Hello"];
NSMutableString *string2 = string1;
[string2 setString:@"changed"];
```

will accomplish what I think you intend. The first two lines execute similarly to above and you end up with `string1` and `string2` containing the same address. The third line changes what is at the address they both refer to - you have the linkage you intended.

[*] if you are using GC or `retain`/`release` change the rhs of the first line to `[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:"@Hello"]`

Answer (score 4):

You need a pointer to an instance of `NSString`.
Example:

```
NSString *string1 = @"Hello!";
NSString **string2 = &string1; // get the address of string1
*string2 = @"changed"; // set what string2 points to be 'changed'

NSLog(@"string1:%@, string2:%@", string1, *string2); // should print "string1: changed, string2: changed"
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Richard J. Ross III's answer, since they're already pointers — buying you a level of indirection — just make sure that you change what's at the address they're pointing to while leaving it at that address. So, e.g.

```
NSMutableString *string1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"hello"];
NSMutableString *string2 = string1;

[string2 setString:@"changed"];

NSLog(@"string1: %@, string2: %@"); // "string1: changed, string2: changed"
```

It's not really a workable general solution because it goes too much against the flow of normal Cocoa practices, but understanding what's going on with pointers and how they communicate objects is worthwhile.

Comment: The method `-setString:` does not exist in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html). Is this a private API?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII No, I've just been an idiot. It's in `NSMutableString`, and you'll see that I create an `NSMutableString` instance. I just go ahead and use the `NSString *` storage type due to a surplus of copying the original answer. So technically the original is entirely valid and legal but will generate compiler warnings; a quick pointer type change (which I'll effect right now) and you won't even get the warnings.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand, happens to me all the time.