# NSMutableArray accessing array with another variable

Tags: objective-c

I'm having a hard time getting the hang of this. Say I have:

`NSMutableArray *array1` which is already defined and has content.
Now I want to create another variable, `NSMutableArray *array2`.

When I do `[array2 addObject:someObject]`, I want this object to be added to `array1`, not to `array2`. How can I assign `array2` so that if I make any changes to it, it modifies `array1` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do something this:

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutable arrayWithObjects:...];
NSMutableArray *array2 = array1;

[array2 addObject:someObject];
NSLog(@"%@", array1); // should now contain 'someObject'
```

I am confused, however, why are you trying to create two pointers to the same object?

Comment: Hmm..but why is this not the case for NSStrings? If I do `NSString *string2=string1`, then change `string2`, it doesn't change `string1`, but here if I do it with arrays, it does in fact change the original?

Comment: That is because when you set an NSString, you are changing what the pointer points to. You can call methods all you want on a pointer to an object and it will effect any other pointers to that object, but changing what that object points to requires another level of indirection.

Comment: For more information on misdirection, check out the answer I have here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154817/simple-copying-pointers-with-objective-c/9154838#9154838

Comment: @mohabitar no problem, just remember to accept the answer by pressing the checkmark next to the answer :)

Comment: further to the above comments, references to an NSString object are immutable, whereas NSMutableArray (as the name suggests) is mutable. this means, whenever you call a method on an NSString that "changes it" in some way, it's not really changing the original object, but creating a copy and changing that copy. NSMutableArray however, is by it's nature mutable (can change), therefore 2 ivars that point to the same mutable array point to the same changeable object. I hope this clears this up.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your meaning correctly, you are looking for the `array2` to become an *alias* for `array1`. All you need to do is assign `array1` to `array2`:

```
NSMutableArray *array2 = array1;
```

Now calling `[array2 addObject:someObject]` would add elements to `array1`.

However, `array2` is not a copy of `array1`: it is only *another name for* `array1`. If you create a copy, it would be *completely independent* of the original. In particular, adding elements to a copy would not change the content of the original in any way.