# why in objective c NSString works as value type?

Tags: objective-c

why in objective c NSString works as value type? when I write code

```
NSString *s1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"]; //;
NSString *s2 = s1;
s1 = @"7";

NSLog(@"s1 = %@", s1);
NSLog(@"s2 = %@", s2);
```

result is

```
s1 = 7
s2 = 1
```

why ?

but when I make a class

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,nonnull,retain) NSString *string;

@end

MyObject *o1 = [[MyObject alloc]init];
    o1.string = @"1";
    MyObject *o2 = o1;
    o1.string = @"7";

    NSLog(@"01 = %@", o1.string);
    NSLog(@"02 = %@", o2.string);
```

result is

```
01 = 7
02 = 7
```

Comment: This is the correct behavior for _any_ type.

Comment: thanks for link of same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154817/simple-copying-pointers-with-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't act as a value type.

The second line causes `s2` to point to the same memory location as `s1` points to **at that moment in time**.  That you then change `s1` to point somewhere else is completely irrelevant.